# Why is it only necessary to give operational definition of physical quantities and not also what they really are?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, definition

Poincare in science and hypothesis wrote:

> When we say force is the cause of motion we talk metaphysics, and this definition, if we were content with it, would be absolutely sterile. For a definition to be of any use, it must teach us to measure force; moreover, that suffices; it is not at all necessary that it teach what force is in itself, nor whether it is the cause or the effect of motion.

But I want to know why for definition of force (or any physical quantity) *it is not at all necessary that it teach what force is in itself?*

Similar thing is mentioned in "An
introduction To
Mechanics by Daniel Kleppner" (pg. 60):

> Once a physical quantity has been defined in terms of a measurement procedure, we must appeal to experiment, not to preconceived notions, to understand its properties. To contrast this operational viewpoint with a non-operational approach, consider, for example, Newton’s definition of time: “Absolute, true, and mathematical time, of itself, and from its own nature, flows equally without relation to anything external.” This may be philosophically and psychologically appealing, but it is difficult to see how to make use of such a definition. Newton’s idea of time is metaphysical (beyond physics).

Why is it **only necessary** to give [operational definition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_definition) of time (or force, time, length...) and **not also** what they really are?

Please note that the question is not *"Why giving operational definition is necessary?"* . The question is *"Why giving operational definition is sufficient?"*

Also I have another question related to this topic that:

Newton didn't gave any operational definition of mass, time, space..... doesn't that makes Newtonian mechanics *useless* ? Similarly Euclid didn't gave any operational definition of point, line... so again doesn't that make Euclidean Geometry *useless*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is necessary because the operational definition *is* what the quantity really is. As Eddington put it

> *“A physical quantity is defined by the series of operations and calculations of which it is the result.”* Eddington A.S., 1923, *The Mathematical Theory of Relativity*, CUP.

Assuming that something else is the physical quantity is metaphysics. There is no justification for it, and actually it does not make sense. Also, understanding that the operational definition is the definition is essential to a proper understanding of the mathematical structure not only of relativity (the context in which Eddington was writing), but also the mathematical structure of quantum mechanics, in which physical quantities exist in measurement but do not necessarily exist between measurements.

> *“In the general case we cannot speak of an observable having a value for a particular
> state, but we can … speak of the probability of its having a specified
> value for the state, meaning the probability of this specified value being obtained
> when one makes a measurement of the observable.”* Dirac P.A.M., 1958, *Quantum Mechanics*, Clarendon Press, p.47.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is it only necessary to give operational definition of time (or force, time, length...) and not also what they really are?

It is only necessary since, to the extent that we can indeed determine what a physical entity "really is", we must do so *after* having defined it operationally and having performed experiments with it.

It would be pointless to define, say, a "photon" as an excitation of the electromagnetic field if we did not know how to associate the words "electromagnetic field" to anything concrete like an antenna or a photodetector.
However, after having operationally defined a "photon" as the thing which makes the photodetector "click" we can go on to describe it with an object called the "electromagnetic field", which we can then call "more fundamental" if we like.

> Newton didn't gave any operational definition of mass, time, space..... doesn't that makes Newtonian mechanics useless ? Similarly Euclid didn't gave any operational definition of point, line... so again doesn't that make Euclidean Geometry useless?

Newton was not *explicit* about what he meant by "time" in an operational sense but he knew how to measure it; similarly, Euclid knew what he meant by a point and a line.

The definitions in Newtonian mechanics and Euclidean geometry are useful since they can be operationalized; when introducing the topic to a student today the operational approach to, say, mechanics is probably more instructive of the way that science is practised today than to start off by reading Newton.

Edit:
To clarify, I meant to say that the definition used in the scientific investigation of a concept is only the operational one: it is both sufficient and necessary to have it.
I gather you're satisfied with it being necessary and would like to see why it is also sufficient.
I'd argue that it is sufficient since we do not need anything more than it to start doing experiments: we can design them to study the nature of the phenomenon we see even if we have no idea about what it is a manifestation of.

For example, if an astronomer sees a periodic radio signal coming from a specific direction they need not know whether it comes from a neutron star, black hole or anything else --- in fact, there is no need for them to even know what those objects are.
The signal is the phenomenon, its operational definition is clear ("the signal with a period of such and such coming from the coordinates..."), and it can be analyzed.

Any investigation into the "true nature" of a phenomenon does not need to be included in its *definition*.

Comment: You are saying that after giving operational definition of physical quantity we can determine *what that physical quantity really is* after doing experiments. (No?) We know the operational definition of time ie we measure it by a clock. So have we been able to know What time really is?  You may say we don't know what time is because we have not been able to do such experiments from which we can know what it is , so how about length, space ...... do you know definition of any physical quantity, a defination which have no contradiction or any philosophical problem?

Comment: Also you are not answering the question ie "Why is it **sufficient** to give OPD?" . You are answering "Why is it necessary (not "only  necessary" =sufficient) to give OPD?"

Comment: @Zenra I have edited my answer to address the point about sufficiency. As for the first comment, it is not really clear to me what the question is: in physics, we do not really answer "what it really is"-type questions; instead we seek to describe and predict observable phenomena.

Answer (score 0):

The laws of physics are mathematical expressions of variables that stand for numbers.  In order to actually use a law, rather than just looking at it and admiring it, we need some way of measuring the quantity so as to provide a number to use in the law.  That is, in order to use the law it is sufficient to have an operational definition.